# Oracledataadaptor Fillschema doesnot work with novalidate table constraint

Tags: c#, odp.net

I am using ODP.net for updating a table with C# winform. I get Dynamic SQL error if my oracle table constraint has novalidate. If I do not have that the delete/edit works fine.

Please tell how to fix this issue other than below options
1. setting primarykey manually in the code since the code is generic.
2. Remove novalidate within constarint in oracle table.

---

Oracle table constarint:

```
ALTER TABLE "table1" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_table1" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID") ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

C# code:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OracleConnection OraConn;
        OracleDataAdapter FOraDataAdapt;
        DataTable OraDataTable;
        BindingSource FBindSource;
        int RecNo;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OraConn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=ORCL1;User Id=123;Password=123;");
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OraConn.Open();

                OracleCommand FOraCommand = new OracleCommand("select * from table1", OraConn);
                FOraDataAdapt = new OracleDataAdapter(FOraCommand);                   OracleCommandBuilder FOraCommandBuilder = new OracleCommandBuilder(FOraDataAdapt);
                OraDataTable = new DataTable();

                DataTable TableSchema = new DataTable();
                FOraDataAdapt.Fill(OraDataTable);
                FOraDataAdapt.FillSchema(TableSchema, System.Data.SchemaType.Source);

                FBindSource = new BindingSource();
                FBindSource.DataSource = OraDataTable;

                grdView.DataSource = FBindSource; 

            }
            catch (Exception Exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Exp.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RecNo = FBindSource.Position;
                FBindSource.RemoveAt(RecNo);
                FOraDataAdapt.Update(OraDataTable);            
                OraDataTable.Rows[RecNo].AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception Exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Exp.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecNo = FBindSource.Position;
            OraDataTable.Rows[RecNo].BeginEdit();
        }

        private void btnPost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FBindSource.EndEdit();
                FOraDataAdapt.Update(OraDataTable);
                OraDataTable.Rows[RecNo].AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception Exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Exp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```